# resources on eventlet

Tags: python, eventlet

hi
i am actually working on a project which needs realtime updates so we are using eventlet for that so can u guys refer to resources to read about eventlet given the fact that i have no
previous experience of using eventlet or any realtime library for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Their [patterns page](http://eventlet.net/doc/design_patterns.html#design-patterns) could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a lack of good documentation for Eventlet. Here are some resources I've found helpful:

http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html

https://convore.com/django-community/why-dont-more-people-use-eventlet/

https://github.com/ckreutzer/eventlet-django-webchat

http://unethicalblogger.com/2010/08/28/unclog-the-tubes-blocking-detection-in-eventlet.html